# How to add custom description to Spark Job for displaying in Spark Web UI

Tags: apache-spark

When we submit application to Spark, and after performing any operation Spark Web UI displays Job and Stages like `count at MyJob.scala:15`. But in my application there are multiple `count` and `save` operations are there. So it is very difficult to understand UI. Instead of `count at MyJob.scala:15`, can we add custom description to give more detailed information to job.

While googling found https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3468 and https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/2342, author attached [image](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/4736016/6936886/e35fd582-d891-11e4-980d-8de13f50e442.png), with detailed description like 'Count', 'Cache and Count', 'Job with delays'. So can we achieve same? I am using Spark 2.0.0.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

use the [`sc.setJobGroup`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.setJobGroup):

**Examples:**
python:

```
In [28]: sc.setJobGroup("my job group id", "job description goes here")
In [29]: lines = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4])
In [30]: lines.count()
Out[30]: 4
```

Scala:

```
scala> sc.setJobGroup("my job group id", "job description goes here")
scala> val lines = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4))
scala> lines.count()
res3: Long = 4
```

**SparkUI:**

[image: job description screen shot]

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Note, if you happen to be using an `org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession` (which was added later to unify all the different sql, spark, and hive contexts), then just use `yourSparkSession.sparkContext` to set this in the SparkContext.

Answer (score 3):

Note that new Zeppelin 0.8 loose his tracking hook if you change the JobGroup name, and can't display his job progress bar (job still working, no effect on the job itself)

You can use

```
sc.setLocalProperty("callSite.short","my job description")
sc.setLocalProperty("callSite.long","my job details long description")
```

instead

See
[How to change job/stage description in web UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903342/how-to-change-job-stage-description-in-web-ui)
for some screen captures and scala syntax

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does your answer also mean that we should prefer `c.setLocalProperty` over `sc.setJobGroup`? If so, I will point future readers to your answer. I am currently not working on [tag:apache-spark], if you are, you might tell that :)

Comment: How to enable the same for %sql paragraphs in Zeppelin?